# Eloquent: Do I need to do this query raw?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm rewriting parts of legacy software using laravel/eloquent.

my understanding of typical eloquent is good and I've done some projects in laravel but not so much for legacy code.

I'm trying to do this in eloquent which creates 79 rows:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `ps_module_shop` (`id_module`, `enable_device`, id_shop) (SELECT `id_module`, `enable_device`, 555 FROM ps_module_shop WHERE `id_shop` = 1);
```

I've read you can only do bulk insert with `model::insert` but I'm not sure how to do so with this query specifically, other than pure sql.

This is how I'm doing it for now, but raw sql feels more elegant for this query:

```
$blkInsert = [];
$tplModuleShop = ModuleShop::where('id_shop', 1)->get();
foreach($tplModuleShop as $mshop) {
    $blkInsert[] = [
        'id_module'     => $mshop->id_module,
        'enable_device' => $mshop->enable_device,
        'id_shop'       => $shop->id_shop,
    ];
}
ModuleShop::insert($blkInsert);
```

Note: I know this is a pivot table, but it is legacy db that uses composite keys so I decided to treat it as its own model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a way to do it with DB::select (although still doing the sql part "raw")

```
    $fixCollection = function($collection) {
        return json_decode(json_encode($collection), true);
    };

    ModuleShop::insert(
        $fixCollection(
            \DB::select("SELECT `id_module`, `enable_device`, {$shop->id_shop} as id_shop FROM ps_module_shop WHERE `id_shop` = 1")
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this might just be easier using your sql statement... here is my attempt:

```
DB::table('ps_model_shop')
    ->insert(DB::table('ps_module_shop')
        ->select(['id_module', 'enable_device'])
        ->where('id_shop', 1)
        ->get()
        ->map(function($module){
            $module['id_shop'] = 555;
        })
        ->toArray()
    );
```

Comment: Edited the code to make it work, needed fix collection because the array elements are still objects. Accepting this answer as it does not use any raw sql. But raw sql is probably the way to go.

Comment: @AvedisKiyici cool thanks. Don’t forget to use parameterized queries with ? If those numbers are user input